# how to continue the game from where it is stopped in android

Tags: android

I am developing game application in Android.

I Created continue Button in the game screen.

"If user chooses continue, it
should resume the game from the level which it has already stopped. Get the
level from XML and directly jump that level. "

how can i do it

Answer (score 0):

Use the callbacks in the Games Activity to store and retrieve the information when it's needed. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle `onPause()` and `onResume()` are probably what you're interested in.